# Python, clear big list efficiently

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I need to clear a huge `list` which contains approximately 350k complex arrays. It basically took 2 min just to clear it with all 3 ways of clearing a `list` (`del data_list[:]`, `data_list.clear()` or `data_list = []`).

As suggested in the comments, I'll elaborate the case. By "complex arrays", I mean ndarray of complex numbers. The following codes reproduce the case.

```py
import numpy as np
data_list = [np.zeros((4, 408), dtype=complex) for _ in range(350000)]
data_list = []  # this takes fairly long time
```

One workaround I can think of is to make the list a local variable, but it's kinda hard to do due to the need to read log dynamically in my code.

So, is there an efficient way of clearing a big list?

Any advice can be helpful. Really appreciate it.

---

> can you make it a numpy array?

- Since number of arrays may vary, I guess `list` is better to append data dynamically. Correct me if I'm wrong.

### UPDATE

With the help of @6502, we found out that the issue is actually a potential bug with core Python on Windows.

Comment: can you make it a numpy array? I think clearing numpy arrays is a lot faster than normal built-in arrays.

Comment: Please provide a more concrete example of what you are doing. What, **exactly** do you mean by "complex arrays"? Note, 350k is nothing. If is do `my_list = [object() for _ in range(350000)]` then `my_list.clear()` it is instantaneous. Note, `data_list = []` **is not** equivalent to `data_list.clear()`, although both might cause the objects being referred to inside `data_list` to be garbage collected,  but why that's taking so long depends on exactly what's in that list, not the list itself, which is tiny, and clearing it actually takes no time, it would be other stuff that happens

Comment: That's 9 entire gigabytes worth of arrays. I hope you have plenty of memory.

Comment: Is clearing the list actually your bottleneck? 2 minutes is a while, but doing your actual *work* on 9 gigabytes worth of data is probably going to take a lot longer than that.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I got 32 GB of memory locally and even bigger in the sever, so memory size isn't what I concern actually.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica By profiling, I could see that clearing this list actually takes 85% of the entire data processing procedure lol.

Comment: No way. Not possible. Either you're misreading the profiling output, or the profiler is attributing the execution time to the wrong code.

Comment: 2 minutes seemed long even for this, since freeing an array doesn't involve traversing its buffer, but it seemed within the realm of plausibility if the ndarray type's deallocation routine was slower than I expected. After timing, I can confirm that deallocation is nowhere near that slow. Creating the big list of arrays could plausibly take that long on a slower system than I tested, but not destroying it.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I ran the codes in debug mode step by step. What's more, I ran the example codes in Python Console. The results were the same - clearing the list took way longer than any other part of the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest part in your code snippet is taken on allocation (on my system 0.56s), not deallocation (on my system 0.07s).

```
import numpy as np, time, gc 
print("1") 
start = time.time() 
#gc.disable() 
data_list = [np.zeros((4, 408), dtype=complex) for _ in range(350000)] 
mid = time.time() 
#gc.enable() 
print("2") 
data_list = []  # "this takes fairly long time" (doesn't for me)
end = time.time() 
print("3") 
print(mid-start, end-mid)
```

My guess <strike>is</strike> **was** that because elements are big the garbage collector is triggered many times during the allocation loop <strike>(didn't verify)</strike> **but it's not; even disabling garbage collection around the allocation doesn't speed up the code on my system**.

Making it a single array with

```
 data = np.zeros((350000, 4, 408), dtype=complex)
 data = []
```

is immediate as it's a single big memory object allocated and deallocated in one go. Of course it's not a `list` object so the behavior is not exactly the same.

If your code is taking a lot on deallocation may be the problem is main memory trashing (i.e. paging). 350000x4x408 is about 500 millions and that number of double-precision complex numbers would take in a numpy array about 9Gb (and a lot more as `complex` Python objects).

If you don't have that amount of free RAM then managing it relying on virtual memory is going to be a pain and indeed the observable symptom could be that when processing is terminated a lot of time is need to "page back in" all the stuff that was deallocated to make room for the data.

If this is the case then even having all your data in a single memory block wouldn't speed up much (the time is spent getting back the 9Gb that was discarded, not the deallocation itself).

On Windows systems the damage to system performance could even be "permanent" in case of entering trash mode: in other words the system may be is not able to recover to normal speed until next reboot. This was happening many years ago (Windows XP) and I don't use Windows regularly... may be recent versions fixed the problem.

### UPDATE

As you tested the script and still deallocation takes 2 minutes I think the explanation can be in the python or numpy distribution.
To check where the problem is you can replace

```
 np.zeros((4, 408), dtype=complex)
```

with

```
 array.array("d", [0.0]) * (2*4*408))
```

to allocate the same amount of memory using only standard Python objects; if the issue remains then the problem is in core python, otherwise it's in numpy. In both cases I'd submit a bug report... may be it's a known problem on windows and the answer will be "wontfix" but seems strange as deallocation on my Linux system takes less than 1sec and my system doesn't seem to be 120 times more powerful than yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as mentioned in the question, number of arrays may vary, which means I can't get the exact number of arrays (350k in the example) at the beginning.

Comment: My system has 32GB of RAM, so I guess virtual memory won't be the problem here.

Comment: @MrCrHaM: it's not the amout of RAM you have the critical point, it's the amout of **free** RAM you have.

Comment: I've been monitoring the usage of RAM the entire time, and it's far from reaching the maximum. The peak memory usage is about 20GB.

Comment: @MrCrHaM: during the 2 minutes what is the computer doing? is 100% CPU?

Comment: Not exactly. During the 2 minutes, CPU utilization is about 30%. And for other parts of the codes, CPU utilization is about 20%. BTW, my CPU is Intel i7 8700 @ 3.2GHz, and my system is runing on Win 10 Pro.

Comment: @MrCrHaM: if you run the code snippet I've added to the answer what are the results you see with and without gc disabling?

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I'll just post the processing time here. With gc enabled, the result is `3.9030470848083496 123.07695126533508`; with gc disenabled, the result is `3.902038812637329 123.38439297676086`. So they are pretty much the same.

Comment: @MrCrHaM: that is very strange and if you're using a standard distribution of Python and numpy it would IMO qualify as a bug. To see if the problem is in numpy or in core python try using `import array` and `array.array("d", [3.14])*(4*408*2)` instead of `np.zeros` call to use the same amount of memory using only standard Python objects. If the problem remains then the issue is in core python, if not it's in numpy. On my system (arch linux, Python 3.8.2, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz) deallocation is less than 1sec.

Comment: @MrCrHaM: Maybe you've got some weird debug stuff going on. Maybe you're running with Valgrind or something else that could change allocation behavior, or you have a debug build of some component involved.

Comment: Check what happens if you use `ones` instead of `zeros`, to guarantee that all the memory is written to before deallocation.

Comment: I've replace `np.zeros` with `array` as you suggested, and the results remains the same. Also I've tried it on Linux, deallocation takes less than 1 sec just like you mentioned. So I guess it's a core pytthon issue when running on Win 10 Pro. I thought it's a common Python behaviour from the beginning lol. Thank you so much for all the effort to help me spot the issue.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I did as you suggested, the issue remains. It seems something is wrong with core python on Win 10 Pro.